# How to Solve Kotlin Version Problem in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart

The current Kotlin version is 1.9.22. I updated '' with '1.9.22', but I'm still encountering the same error even after updating.

```
[Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                     │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then │
│ update C:\Users\karth\Desktop\karthik\android\build.gradle:                     │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'                                                    │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't done it. Check your **gradle-wrapper.properties**

For distributionUrl path: **android/gradle/wrapper /gradle-wrapper.properties**

And change it to the latest gradle version to match your kotlin version

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.5-all.zip
```